# не загружается аватар личного профиля

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

как я понял вся проблема в этой строчке:

```
mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE `users` SET `avatar` = '$apend' WHERE ".$_SESSION['user']['user_id']- 
>user_id);
```

пробывал писать по разному, тут либо все аватарки в базе меняются, либо вообще не работает.
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Как называется столбец с идентификатором пользователя? Каков тип идентификатора?

Comment: @anton это не имеет ни малейшего значения :)